# WooCommerce converted variations select field to radio buttons but not changing price value when checked

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I used the filter `woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_html` to convert the variation select field to radio buttons, but I cannot get the price value to change on check or add to cart action to initialize. An error notice is triggered due to no selection detected.

**How do I get the results to display?**

[image: image of radio buttons]

Fail message when add to cart triggered
[image: image of fail]

### Code

```php
add_filter('woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_html',function($html, $args) 
{
    $args = wp_parse_args(apply_filters('woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_args', $args), [
    'options'          => false,
    'attribute'        => false,
    'product'          => false,
    'selected'         => false,
    'name'             => '',
    'id'               => '',
    'class'            => '',
    'show_option_none' => 'Choose an option',
    ]);

    if( false === $args['selected'] && $args['attribute'] && $args['product'] instanceof WC_Product ) {
        $selected_key     = 'attribute_'.sanitize_title($args['attribute']);
        $args['selected'] = isset($_REQUEST[$selected_key]) ? wc_clean(wp_unslash($_REQUEST[$selected_key])) : $args['product']->get_variation_default_attribute($args['attribute']);
    }

    $options               = $args['options'];
    $product               = $args['product'];
    $attribute             = $args['attribute'];
    $name                  = $args['name'] ? $args['name'] : 'attribute_'.sanitize_title($attribute);
    $id                    = $args['id'] ? $args['id'] : sanitize_title($attribute);
    $class                 = $args['class'];
    $show_option_none      = (bool)$args['show_option_none'];
    $show_option_none_text = $args['show_option_none'] ? $args['show_option_none'] : 'Choose an option';

    if( empty($options) && !empty($product) && !empty($attribute) ) {
        $attributes = $product->get_variation_attributes();
        $options    = $attributes[$attribute];
    }
    
    //get cmse custom attribute fieldtype option
    $attid = wc_attribute_taxonomy_id_by_name(str_replace('pa_','',$attribute));
    $ftype = get_option('cmsewoo_attrib_fieldtype_'.$attid);
    
    if( isset($ftype) && $ftype == 'radio' ) 
    {
        $html='';

        if( !empty($options) ) 
        {
            if( $product && taxonomy_exists($attribute) ) 
            {
                $terms = wc_get_product_terms($product->get_id(),$attribute,['fields' => 'all']);
                foreach($terms as $term) 
                {
                    if( in_array($term->slug, $options, true) ) 
                    {
                        $label = esc_html(apply_filters('woocommerce_variation_option_name', $term->name, $term, $attribute, $product));
                        $selected = checked(sanitize_title($args['selected']), $term->slug, false);
                        $extattr = ' class="'.esc_attr($class).' btn-check" data-attribute_name="attribute_'.esc_attr(sanitize_title($attribute)).'" data-show_option_none="'.($show_option_none ? 'yes' : 'no').'"';
                        
                        $html .= '
                        <input type="radio" name="'.esc_attr($name).'" id="'.esc_attr($id).'_'.$term->term_id.'"'.$extattr.' '.$selected.' />
                        <label for="'.esc_attr($id).'_'.$term->term_id.'" class="btn btn-primary">'.$label.'</label>
                        '; 
                    }
                }
            }else{
                
            }
            // this makes the button enabled
            add_filter('woocommerce_get_script_data','get_btn_data',10,2);
        }
    }
    
    return $html;
}, 20, 2);

function get_btn_data($data,$handle)
{
    if( $handle == 'wc-add-to-cart-variation' ) {
        $data = [];
    }
    
    return $data;
}
```

**The option in the attributes admin to set radio type**
[image: attribute field type setting]

Comment: U need more than just changing some html. I would suggest use one of the many plugins or download and investigate the steps. Here is one free - https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-variation-swatches/

Comment: I believe you have to hook your selection to add-to-cart-variation.js